# How to properly upgrade from bootstrap 3.3.7 to 4.0 on an Angular 6 project

Tags: bootstrap-4, upgrade, angular6

I am developing my first Angular 6 project and, first, I installed Bootstrap 3.3.7 (via npm)

Now I have seen [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) some carousels and things that I would like to implement on my project but BS 4.0 is needed.

How should I do the upgrade in a safe way? I tried myself but I must have broken something because project stopped compiling. I restored the backup and I would like to do it right now.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following steps can help you.

1. Find a file in your project root directory named **package.json**.
2. In that file go to **dependencies** object. Find `"bootstrap":"^3.3.7"`.
3. Modify that entry to `"bootstrap":"^4.0.0"`.
4. Run `npm install` in your project root directory.

The above steps successfully install **bootstrap-4** in your node_modules.

To use bootstrap .js and .css files you have to import them in your **angular.json** file.

To do that go to **styles** array in your **angular.json** file and import bootstrap .css files as below:

```
"styles":[
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
]
```

To import bootstrap .js files go to **scripts** array in your **angular.json** and import as below:

```
"scripts":[
   "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
]
```

Now compile your code with **ng build** or **ng serve**. It will work smoothly. Let me know if it throws any error.

Comment: I found sliders for my actual BS version but I think your answer can help me if someday I have to upgrade.I will tell you if it works properly.

Comment: Mind you that Bootstrap 4 is a major rewrite and may result in a messy ui. The process is more complex than just upgrading the version, as explained here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/

Answer (score 4):

If you you want to get the Latest Version from Bootstrap just run

```
npm install bootstrap@latest
```

run

```
npm install bootstrap@next
```

to get the latest beta...